# Validate a form by using jQuery or struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2

I'm wondering if jQuery is enough for validation (eg: validate a login form.) Why we use Struts2 to do this?

Regards
Liam

Comment: jQuery should be enough, maybe. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: But you should always validate your input on the server side in addition to validating it on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a recipe but for security reasons, you should validate your application from the server and the cliente side

[in this question that i made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936020/security-problem-with-form-and-javascript) speak about some points of security. So hopefully read this to get some considerations for client and server side validations

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jorge. You must do server side validation. Because your script based validation can be bypassed if user disable JavaScript in their browser. So server side validation always useful.